# gcov giving error: No executable lines

Tags: googletest, gcov

I am using gcov to test the code coverage in my project. The gcov is giving me output of the test files that i have written using gtest, but it is not giving me the correct output of the actual implementation files. It gives the message "No executable lines". The project is based in QT and C++. Any pointers in this regard will be helpful since I am new to both QT and gtest/gcov.

Some more info:
1. Executed the test binary built using gtest
2. The .o, .gcda and .gcno files are in the same folder
3. I am executing gcov from the location of the source with the -o option to specify the path of the bin files.

Answer (score 3):

This was happening because I had not copied the .gcda files to the directory with the .gcno and .o files. After copying the .gcda files and running the gcov it is running fine. :)